# How to know if app/game was launched via notification on Android?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I'm making a game in Unity for Android. I have implemented a notification system. Notifications show and clicking on them opens the game. The thing I'm stuck on is how to know if the game/app is launched by tapping the notification?

Here is the java code for the notification plugin I'm using https://github.com/GoShikhar/unity-android-notifications/blob/master/PluginSrc/app/src/main/java/net/agasper/unitynotification/UnityNotificationManager.java

This is my manifest https://github.com/GoShikhar/unity-android-notifications/blob/master/UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml

In my unity start scene I use this to check for intent messages.

```
void Start(){
 AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
 var activityObject = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
 AndroidJavaObject intent = activityObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
 int NotificationID = intent.Call<int>("getIntExtra", "id", -1);
 print("NOTIFDICATION ID " + NotificationID);
 bool hasExtra = intent.Call<bool>("hasExtra", "arguments");
 string arguments = null;
 if (hasExtra)
 {
    AndroidJavaObject extras = intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getExtras");
    arguments = extras.Call<string>("getString", "title");
    print("title : " + arguments);
    arguments = extras.Call<string>("getString", "message");
    print("message: " + arguments);
 }

 if (arguments != null)
 {
        print("App opened via notification");
 }
}
```

This not working. The default notification ID is being printed i.e. -1. Also title and message are null. Even though the notification has the title and message parameter.

I have seen lots of examples for Android Studio but not for Unity. So any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean deep linking? Perhaps this Github project would be helpful: https://github.com/TROPHiT/UnityDeeplinks.